# Multiple jumps ssh tunnel, one command line

Tags: ssh, redhat, ssh-tunnel

I'm currently connecting my local machine with the target running commands in my local (mobaxterm), in pivotonone and pivottwo, this is the flow of data:

```
mobaxterm <--- pivotone <--- pivottwo <--- target
```

These are the commands that I run on each machine:

```
local(mobaxterm)
ssh -L 5601:127.0.0.1:5601 root@pivotone
pivotone
ssh -L 5601:127.0.0.1:5601 root@pivottwo
pivottwo
ssh -L 5601:127.0.0.1:5601 root@target
```

I was wandering if I could do the same but with just one command in my mobaxterm machine?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `-L` option to manage jump hosts.

```
ssh -J root@pivotone,root@pivottwo root@target
```

You can automate this in your `.ssh/config` file

```
Host target
    ProxyJump root@pivotone,root@pivottwo
```

Then you can simply run

```
ssh root@target
```

Comment: Thanks chepner , but Im having trouble to understand, where do I specify the port, in your first example